# IIF in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have written like this in my aspx page

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUserType" runat="server" Text='<%# Response.Write(IIF(Eval("MyBool"),"OFF","ON")) %>'
                    CommandName='<%# Response.Write(IIF(Eval("MyBool"),"TurnOff","TurnOn")) %>' 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MyRowIdentifier") %>' />
```

but it is saying "The name IIF does not existing in the current context, and also I have searched many ways all are saying working but myne it is not, where am doing wrong please let me know

Comment: Consider adding link/information why you believe some `IIF` *should* be working.

Comment: you don't need the Respnse.Write and you have much more flexibility if you handle this in the GridView RowDatabound event.

Comment: please let me know the flexibility that you want to tell me

Comment: orelse please let me the same code in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using C# for code behind then C# does not support IIf function.
Its VB.Net who supports for IIF function.

Comment: Not only that, but the conditional operator would be a better choice: [?: Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov and Ashish Bisht: I want to use ON/OFF buttons in gridview column so that I need to update data base accordingly, please suggest me how can I use this feature in c#.net

Comment: Better if you put the case expression in your sql query or Stored procedure for this . Then no need to use do extra things.

Comment: I have completed it with aspx and c# code thanks for your seggestions

Answer (score 0):

### Use ternary operator as follows:

CommandName='<%# Eval("MyBool") ? "TurnOff" : "TurnOn" %>'